# Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I am getting the above mentioned error. Below is my code snippet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/autoComplete/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/core.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/customlook.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/Header.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/Test.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/autoComplete/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/autoComplete/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/advanced_search_filters.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dateJs/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dateJs/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dateJs/datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/user.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('testing');
    $("#CARD_HOLDER_NAME").autocomplete({
      source : '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/cardHolderName'
     });
    });
</script>
```

Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing/wrongly placed **jQuery/ jQuery UI.js/ autocomplete.js files** and the order should be

```
(1) jQuery.js
(2) jQuery UI.js
(3) autocomplete.js
```

Add the following before autocomplete

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however I have added jquery-ui.min.js and jquery.min.js. So should I replace the existing js files with files that you have mentioned and from where i can get  autocomplete.js. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3042288 Get the jQuery UI bundler from here http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip

Comment: @user3042288 Better try add only these items `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" />`

Comment: Hi Praveen...The code is working I am getting data from server side but those data is not getting populated at front.. I am returning List<String> from servlet

Comment: I think this code block -- source : '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/cardHolderName' -- is not able to read the response from servlet

Comment: @user3042288 you have to do it using ajax, see this procedure http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp